# Unable to load FullCalendar JS Library in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, static-resources, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar JS Library V6 (lastest version) to build custom calendar for a requirement in lightning component. I have created the static resource and  included the static resource in lightning component. When I am trying to render the calendar it throws an error "FullCalendar is not defined". I checked the network tab in inspect and seen the library script file is loaded. Still I am unable to use this FullCalendar object.
Static Resource Configuration Information

```
<!-- static resource information -->
Name: CalendarLib
MIME Type: text/javascript
Cache Control: Public
<!-- static resource end -->
```

**Lightning Component Code**

```html
<!-- calendar component -->

<aura:component>
  <ltng:require 
      scripts="{! $Resource.CalendarLib }" 
      afterScriptsLoaded="{! c.initCalendar }" 
  />
  <div aura:id="calendar-container"></div>
</aura:component>

<!-- calendar component end -->
```

```js
/* calendar controller */
({
    initCalendar : function(component, event, helper) {
       var calendarContainer = component.find("calendar-container").getElement();
       var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarContainer, calendarConfigObj);
       calendar.render();
    }
})
/* calendar controller end */
```

**Short snippet of library code**

```js
var FullCalendar = (function(e) {})({});
```

I have attempted to establish a binding between the library and the window object in order to utilize "FullCalendar" within a Lightning component. However, I am encountering difficulties and I am seeking assistance in understanding the underlying issue within the system. Additionally, any supplementary tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must attach the library to the global window. In other words, the last line of your static resource should read:

```
window.FullCalendar = FullCalendar;
```

And in your initCalendar function:

```
var calendarContainer = component.find("calendar-container").getElement();
var calendar = new window.FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarContainer, calendarConfigObj);
calendar.render();
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your response, I tried what you suggest and now I am getting this error `[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Calendar')]`. Could you please tell me the reason behind it and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Any luck on FullCalendar v6 with LWC? Does it support LWC?